# 3d stl object is not getting centered after zooming using three js

Tags: angular, three.js, 3d

I have the following code to display the 3d object :-

```
   this.col=new Color().set(this.colorname);
   this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({alpha:true,canvas:this.myCanvas.nativeElement});
   this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth/2,window.innerHeight/2);
   this.scene=new Scene();
   this.scene.background=new Color(0xFFFFFF);
   this.camera=new 
   PerspectiveCamera(this.perspective,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.01,10000);
   this.camera.position.set(500,500,500);
   this.camera.aspect=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;
   this.scene.add( new AmbientLight(0x222222));
   this.scene.add( this.camera );

    var light = new PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
    light.position.z=500;
    light.position.y=500;
    this.camera.add( light );

    var controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera,this.renderer.domElement);

   controls.autoRotate = true;
   controls.autoRotateSpeed = 3.0;
   loader.load(this.filename,geometry =>{
     var material = new MeshPhongMaterial( { color: this.col });
     var mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );
     this.scene.add(mesh);

   })
      this.animate(controls);

}

animate(controls:OrbitControls) {

  this.camera.lookAt( this.scene.position );

  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);

  controls.update();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(_ => this.animate(controls));
}

onWindowResize() {

  this.camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2);
}
}
```

The object when zoomed in is not centered in the canvas.How can I keep the object always at the center of the renderer and perform the tasks like zoom in and zoom out?

Answer (score 0):

You can center a geometry by calling the same named method [center()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.center). Notice that this method call will center the geometry based on its AABB and modify the buffer data permanently.